# Installing SDX trouble org.apache.cocoon.ResourceNotFoundException: No pipeline matched request: index.html

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, tomcat7, apache-cocoon

I'm trying to install [SDX](http://www.nongnu.org/sdx/) to build the [cyberdocs platform](http://www.cyberdocs.org/en).

I'm trying to install into the linux (Debian 3.9.8-1 x86_64 GNU/Linux) with tomcat7.

I'm download the file sdx-2.4.1.3-src.zip from http://download-mirror.savannah.gnu.org/releases/sdx/

When I extract the content I see the following files:

```
├── appendcp.bat
├── bin
├── build
├── build.bat
├── build.sh
├── build.xml
├── create-docs.bat
├── create-docs.sh
├── create-jar.bat
├── create-jar.sh
├── create-war.bat
├── create-war.sh
├── docs
├── INSTALL
├── legal
├── lib
├── LICENSE
├── README
├── run.bat
├── run.sh
├── sdx.bat
├── sdx.sh
├── src
└── tools
```

So, I building the war file then I run the following command to do it:

```
sh build.sh webpp
```

Then I copy the file genereted by the command in this case: **sdx-2.4.1.3-vm1.4.war** in the directory build, I copy this file to
**/usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/**

So I go to the admin panel in tomcat (**localhost:8080/manager/html**) and choose the war file and deploy : sdx-2.4.1.3-vm1.4.war
I restart tomcat and next I go to the URL  **localhost:8080/sdx-2.4.1.3-vm1.4/**

And see the next Trouble:

[image]

```
SDX message  

Source   org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.sitemap.ErrorHandlerHelper
Exception    org.apache.cocoon.ResourceNotFoundException
Message  No pipeline matched request: index.html
Details org.apache.cocoon.ResourceNotFoundException: No pipeline matched request: index.html
extra info
org.apache.cocoon.ResourceNotFoundException: No pipeline matched request: index.html
```

And  the deep mistake:

```java
rg.apache.cocoon.ResourceNotFoundException: No pipeline matched request: index.html
at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.sitemap.PipelineNode.invoke(PipelineNode.java:149)
at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.AbstractParentProcessingNode.invokeNodes(AbstractParentProcessingNode.java:69)
at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.sitemap.PipelinesNode.invoke(PipelinesNode.java:93)
at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.ConcreteTreeProcessor.process(ConcreteTreeProcessor.java:235)
at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.ConcreteTreeProcessor.process(ConcreteTreeProcessor.java:177)
at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.TreeProcessor.process(TreeProcessor.java:253)
at org.apache.cocoon.Cocoon.process(Cocoon.java:699)
at org.apache.cocoon.servlet.CocoonServlet.service(CocoonServlet.java:1154)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

**UPDATE :**

I've run coocon server in the port 8888 an I can see

[image]

So , I try to copy the libraries (*.jar's) genereted in the compilation of coconn 
to libs directory in tomcat7  so:

```
root@demian:/home/cristian/src/cocoon-2.1.12/lib# cp core/*.jar  /usr/share/tomcat7/lib/

root@demian:/home/cristian/src/cocoon-2.1.12/lib# cp optional/*.jar /usr/share/tomcat7/lib/
```

But not found SDX server the libraries of coocon.

Some helpme?

How to fix its trouble?

what do I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for your time and knowledge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs because it is not configured your sitemap, this aplicattion has a sitemap located in `sdx/src/webapp/sitemap.xmap`, you need to edit the line 616, you can see the file like:

```xml
<map:match pattern="">
 <map:redirect-to uri="sdx/"/>
</map:match>
```

So, you need to add the url to entry point like :

```xml
<map:match pattern="index.html">
    <map:redirect-to uri="sdx/admin/superuser.xsp"/>
</map:match>
```